# Need to image a hard drive minus any app or storage histroy

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, hard-drive, software-recommendation

I have a laptop that I used for work. I'm getting ready to give it back to them, but I want to wipe the drive and reinstall with all of the programs that were installed previously and all of the settings the same, but minus any kind of history.
I've had this thing for over 2 years. I'm not worried about anything criminal, I'm just wanting to make sure if their IT dept did a deep dig they wouldn't be able pull anything embarrassing up.
I have, of course, logged out of my Firefox account and uninstalled any 3rd party software I had on there.
Is there anything out there that does this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know if you "need to image" anything. More likely, you need to wipe and reinstall. There is, obviously, not way to selectively delete stuff, without knowing exactly what.

Comment: Did you make any image of the drive when you got the laptop? If so, restore that image.

Answer (score 2):

**It's always best to make a backup before you begin so that if anything goes wrong, you can restore using the backup.**

If you're just worried about your personal stuff like browser history, you can use bleachbit which will overwrite the data.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Run bleachbit as a regular user.

From the main screen of bleachbit, you should probably just select everything on the left menu. Note that it should delete all your browser saved passwords so be sure to back up those profiles before you begin.

Certain things like APT and system files need root privileges so just select everything and if it tells you that you need root access for whatever, you can adjust accordingly.

Also, make sure to click **EDIT** and then select **Preferences** and then make sure the option **"overwrite contents of files to prevent recovery"** is selected as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

You may also be interested in overwriting your `/temp` directory and your swapfile. For those you could probably use a tool like `secure-delete` but just keep in mind that doing so is more dangerous so you should always be careful when running overwriting tools as root. Asking a separate question about that specific use (overwriting `/temp` and/or your swapfile using `secure-delete`) may yield more answers.

Another thing to consider is overwriting any free space on the disk in order to overwrite files that have been deleted that still exist in physical form on the disk. To do this, you will need to run bleachbit as root.

Running bleachbit as root is a bit more dangerous so be careful.

Run bleachbit as root and again, select everything on the menu to the left.

Also, make sure the option to **overwrite contents of files to prevent recovery** is selected.

Comment: +1 just for "It's always best to make a backup before you begin so that if anything goes wrong, you can restore using the backup." The first thing I do when I get a new system is Clonezilla it.